# autoPyTorch installation error in windows

Tags: pytorch

Doing

```
pip install autoPyTorch
```

from https://pypi.org/project/autoPyTorch/
in windows

```
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\ga\anaconda3\envs\automlpy395\lib\site-packages (from torch->autoPyTorch) (3.7.4.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: ConfigSpace, netifaces
  Building wheel for ConfigSpace (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\GA\anaconda3\envs\autoMLpy395\python.exe' 'C:\Users\GA\anaconda3\envs\autoMLpy395\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\G~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpiv0eeai5'
       cwd: C:\Users\GA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78zfdmqt\configspace_985d1975f54b489c8878a152ed6c7358
  Complete output (40 lines):
  C:\Users\GA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-c1p7qiob\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace
  copying ConfigSpace\__version__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\exception.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace\read_and_write\json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace\read_and_write\pcs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace\read_and_write\pcs_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\read_and_write
  copying ConfigSpace\read_and_write\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\read_and_write
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\cycles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\dag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\classes
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\classes\digraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\classes
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\classes\graph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\classes
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\classes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\classes
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\components
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\components\strongly_connected.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\components
  copying ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\components\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ConfigSpace\nx\algorithms\components
  running build_ext
  cythoning ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.pyx to ConfigSpace\hyperparameters.c
  cythoning ConfigSpace/forbidden.pyx to ConfigSpace\forbidden.c
  cythoning ConfigSpace/conditions.pyx to ConfigSpace\conditions.c
  cythoning ConfigSpace/c_util.pyx to ConfigSpace\c_util.c
  cythoning ConfigSpace/util.pyx to ConfigSpace\util.c
  cythoning ConfigSpace/configuration_space.pyx to ConfigSpace\configuration_space.c
  building 'ConfigSpace.hyperparameters' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ConfigSpace
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\GA\anaconda3\envs\autoMLpy395\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78zfdmqt\\netifaces_1ad66342d17444d8b393a67c1a88ba94\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78zfdmqt\\netifaces_1ad66342d17444d8b393a67c1a88ba94\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\GA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-t35_qwhh'
       cwd: C:\Users\GA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78zfdmqt\netifaces_1ad66342d17444d8b393a67c1a88ba94\
  Complete output (5 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'netifaces' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
  Running setup.py clean for netifaces
Failed to build ConfigSpace netifaces
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ConfigSpace which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have tried

```
pip install --no-use-pep517 autoPyTorch
```

not worked

Tried installing torch first, installed successfully

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

but autoPyTorch throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

**System requirements**

Auto-PyTorch has the following system requirements:

- Linux operating system (for example Ubuntu)
- Python    (>=3.6) (get Python here).
- C++ compiler (with C++11 supports)
- SWIG (version 3.0.* is required; >=4.0.0 is not    supported)

[Github AutoPytorch Installation.rst](https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch/blob/master/docs/installation.rst)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).